# What is the difference between "this medication works on me", "this medication works for me" and "this medication works against me"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What is the difference between "**this medication works on me**", "**this medication works for me**" and "**this medication works against me**"?

[The dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/work_1?q=work) says "**to work**" has 2 separated meanings

> 7- [intransitive] to have the result or effect that you want
>
> His charm doesn't work **on** me (= does not affect or impress me).
>
> 8- ​[intransitive] to have a particular effect
>
> Your age can work **against** you in this job.

It is difficult to understand what is the difference between "**to have the result or effect that you want**" and "**to have a particular effect**". They sound the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This medication works on me = it has the intended medical effect on my body.

This medication works for me = it cures my medical problem.

This medication works against me = it has a bad effect.